# `def` vs `declare` for forward declaration

Tags: clojure, forward-declaration

Clojure, has a `declare` macro that allows you to forward-declare functions or variables. It seems to function exactly as `def`: Both `(declare x)` and `(def x)` create `#<Unbound Unbound: #'user/x>`

When should `(declare x)` be used instead of `(def x)`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both `declare` and `def` do create an unbound var, but there are 3 advantages to using `declare`:

1. You can create multiple vars in one statement, e.g. `(declare x y z)`
2. The vars are tagged with the additional metadata `{:declared true}`
3. Using the word `declare` is arguably more clear and idiomatic

---

`(source declare)`:

```
(defmacro declare
  "defs the supplied var names with no bindings, useful for making forward declarations."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& names] `(do ~@(map #(list 'def (vary-meta % assoc :declared true)) names)))
```

Answer (score 6):

The documentation gives the answer:

```
=> (doc declare)
-------------------------
clojure.core/declare
([& names])
Macro
  defs the supplied var names with no bindings, useful for making forward declarations.
```

[Looking at the implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2645), it's clear that `declare` is defined in terms of `def` and provides a little bit of syntax sugar. So functionally, they're pretty much the same.

The advantage of `declare` is to show intent for a later reader. `(declare x y z)` means I intended to make a forward declaration of those symbols, because the macro is `useful for making forward declarations.`

`(def x) (def y) (def z)` means I'm interning these symbols, but you don't know if I meant to give them definitions and forgot to or whether I'm making forward declarations, or maybe something else subtle.

So, `(declare x)` should be preferred over `(def x)` when you're making a forward declaration, to show mercy on future readers of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`def` always applies to the root binding, even if the var is thread-bound at the point where `def` is called.

`def` yields the var itself (not its value). Throws an exception if symbol is already in the namespace and not mapped to an interned var.

Declare `def`s the supplied var names with no bindings, useful for making forward declarations.